# Reorganize table data to two-column format by repeating the headers and leaving some blank rows

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with data organised like this:

[image: Database]

I have another sheet in which I want to transpose certain cells of each row, and at the same time, leave 5 rows between the end of the first transposed row and the beginning of the following. Like this:

[image]

The real first sheet database has tons of rows, so I'm looking for a way to ease the process, without having to write a formula in each row. It would be great if it could be done by just dragging down the first formulated cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using [modular arithmetics](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093497?hl=en) with row numbers.  I will describe the solution pretending that I,J columns (which you apparently don't want) aren't there; perhaps you should move them to the right. The formula for Column A would be

```
=if(mod(row()-1, 14) < 9, indirect("Data!R1C" & mod(row(), 14), False), )
```

Explanation: The `if` statement is responsible for skipping 5 rows after each 9; the comma at the end of formula is for this purpose. If the row is in a suitable range, meaning that mod(row(), 14) is one of numbers 1-9, `indirect` refers to the cell in Data sheet, row 1, column numbered `mod(row(), 14)`.

The formula for column B is similar, with the exception that the row number is also changing.

```
=if(mod(row()-1, 14) < 9, indirect("Data!R" & floor((row()-1)/14)+2 & "C" & mod(row(), 14), False), )
```

It refers to Data sheet with column number as above and row number `floor(row()/14)+2` - meaning it begins at 2 and increases by 1 every 14 rows.

Comment: Thanks soup. I've changed my sheet a bit, and I've adapted the formula to the new conditions. It has worked well on the first two columns, but now I'm trying to return cells O to AD from 1st sheet in column D of 2nd sheet starting on row 2, and I can't get it to work properly. I've created a complete example sheet so you can get an idea of what I'm aiming to do → https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_gk0YaziUhOZfRbrlfHizMrVu6OT7njIaTUyQaE6Lbs/edit#gid=1152278909

Comment: It should be almost the same as your B column, just add some fixed amount (15, I think) to the column number that comes after "C" in the formula. (15 because this is the number of column O).

Comment: I changed `"c" & mod(row(),18)+15` But then it started at column Q, so I wrote `"c" & mod(row()-2,18)+15` and everything is ok except when I drag down, STEP 1 of 2nd project returns a "-" I've also tried `"C" & mod(row(),18+13)` on column G, but then it returns wood. The yellow cell should be returning 22/06 and all results should be one cell up.

Comment: I see there is also a problem with column B. If you want row #19 to work like row #2, the second argument of Mod must be is 19-2 = 17, not 18.

Comment: You're right, I've fixed that. But I'm still having troubles with the formula on column D. I've managed to make it return the values I want skipping the header row on each project, but only for the first 3 projects., then. the floor formula changes row number on the wrong cell. I've included a note on the example sheet so the problem can be seen easier.

Comment: You are using ROW()/18 in there, should be ROW()/17, so that it increases by 1 every 17 rows.

Comment: But If I change it to 17, then it changes floor number on row #17 instead of row #18...

Comment: Okay, it should have been `floor((row()-1) / 17)` .  So that 1-17 get "0", then 18-34 get "1", etc.